# Can data attributes begin with a number? (e.g. data-1234="")

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

I know that the value of identifiers can't begin with numbers or hyphens, but can data attributes? And if so is there any reason for not using `data--=""` (not that I would, just curiosity speaking)

Comment: An identifier, when it means the value of an `id` attribute as per HTML5 drafts, may begin with any character except space characters (which aren’t allowed at all). In HTML 4.01 and earlier, different rules apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See the definition](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#attr-data-%2a)

> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name
>   starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the
>   hyphen, is XML-compatible, and contains no characters in the range
>   U+0041 to U+005A (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z).

The reason is XML compability. And of course javascript compability because `var 1234` is not possible.

Comment: The answer is rather implicit. You need to check the definition of “XML-compatible” to see that the rules allow a hyphen as well as a digit in an attribute name (though not at the start, but the position after `data-` is not a start position). So data-1234 and data-- are allowed (and the former could make perfect sense, while the latter does not look useful).

Answer (score 0):

Data attributes cannot begin with a number. The HTML will pass as valid however JavaScript's `.querySelector` will throw an error.

`Error getting document: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'DocumentFragment': 'dt[data-label=3DModel]' is not a valid selector.`